# NHibernate vs Entity Framework 5 auto connecting entities

Tags: nhibernate, orm, entity-framework-5

Recently I've come back to the question NHibernate vs EF5 for the Enterprise Application. 
I know many important differences, but this one is the most suprising for me.
Consider two classic entities, Customer and Order (1:n):

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    **public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }**
}

public class Order
{
public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
public virtual Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
public virtual string Number { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    **public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }**
}
```

For both NHibernate and EF5 there are two-way mappings.
Code snippets for loading all customers AND all Orders in context of DbContext and Session for EF5 and NHibernate accordingly:

```
        using (TestOrmForDalDbEntities context = new TestOrmForDalDbEntities())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            IQueryable<Customer> customers = context.Customers;
            customers.Load();

            IQueryable<Order> orders = context.Orders;
            orders.Load();
        }



using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var customers = session.Query<Customer>().ToList();
    var orders = session.Query<Order>().ToList();
```

}

The result is:

EF5: Each Customer has a collection of appropriate Orders (EF5 automatically connect them)
NHibernate: None of Customers has a collection of appropriate Orders. Even though each Order HAS link to an appropriate Customer.

The question is: is it an NHibernate idea not to connect in such way or it's me who doesn't know how to configure NHibernate?

P.S. Mappings for NHibernate:

```
    public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Orders).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public OrderMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Number);
        Map(x => x.Date);
        Map(x => x.CustomerId);
        References(x => x.Customer);
```

}

Comment: There is most likely something wrong in your mapping in the nhibernate sample. Could you show your mappings as well?

Comment: 2 Mattias: I've added the mappings

Comment: Just as an experiment, can you remove the mapping of the CustomerId for the NH test. There is a remote possibility (in my mind) that it might help.

Answer (score 0):

The relation from Customers to Orders (HasMany) should be Inverse, meaning, it's the Order endpoint that has the foreign key to the Customer.